# Loading from URL not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I'm trying to load an image (JPG) from a url using the following asynctask method.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

I'm executing this method in onCreate like this

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).execute(final_url);
```

But I can't see any image and when I debugged it, I found the value of `mIcon11` to be null. What am I doing wrong

PS : The `final_url` goes like this

```
www.website.com/somelink/IMG 005_153.JPG
```

Comment: btw you have to encode your url because it has a space ;), Where are you executing this? in onCreate? Try to init your ImageView in oncreate and store it as global value in your activity and pass it to your task

Comment: Guess that's the problem. Can you tell me a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your finalurl`http://www.website.com/somelink/IMG%20005_153.JPG` is not returning any thing. Check that..

Try to encode it before using it.

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://...")
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
            .build().toString();
```

or try following

String uri =  URLEncoder.encode(finalurl, "utf-8");

Comment: That is not the actual link. The actual link is http://gateway.ceylonlinux.com/CL_GOLD/view/add_product/upload/BAE 005_153.JPG
The link works

Comment: that's still no accessible, try some general url first, say from google images and see if it works, then check yours.

Comment: The problem is that your url need to be encoded before sending its request.

Comment: A general link works. Guess I'll have to encode the url. Can you tell me how to?

Comment: I have added that in my answered please take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
private class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private Bitmap bitmap;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                URL url;
                url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            im.setImageBitmap(result);
            pb1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

and call it like

```
new ImageLoadTask().execute(STRING URL);
```